# South African with Irish Stamp 4 Travelling to the UK, do I need a visa?

Tags: visas, uk, standard-visitor-visas

I am married to a citizen of the Czech Republic. I currently hold a South African Passport and am residing in Ireland with a temporary Stamp 4 permission until 02/2020 while my 5 year residency is being approved.

I will be travelling to the UK in December to visit my mother and step-father, with my wife, for Christmas.

My query is do I need a visa to travel to the UK on my current Stamp 4 permit? If so, which visa must I apply for? What is the difference between a Stamp 4 and a Stamp 4 EUFAM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to enter the UK as a visa national who is the family member of an EU citizen, you either need a "valid Article 10 residence card" or a family permit. In Ireland, the Article 10 residence card is implemented as the "Stamp 4 EUFAM". Since you don't yet have this, you should [apply for a family permit](https://www.gov.uk/family-permit). The permit is free and should be issued promptly.

Note that it is permitted, once you have the permit, for you to enter the UK through Northern Ireland without going through border control.